# Overloading 'opeator<<' for container type with template class in C++

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

What I tried to do:

```
template <class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& ou, map<T,T> x) {
    for(typename map<T,T>::iterator it = x.begin(); it != x.end(); it++) {
        ou << it->first << ": " << it->second << endl;
    }
    return ou;
}
```

I tested it in the main:

```
int main() {
    map<char, int> m;
    m['a']++;
    m['b']++;
    m['c']++;
    m['d']++;

    cout << m << endl;
}
```

I then got the error:

> 'error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << m'

The overloaded operator would work if I changed the function argument from `map<T,T>` to `map<char,int>`.  Is there a minor issue in my code or is there a completely different way to do this?  How would one go about overloading an operator for a container type in general using a template class?

Comment: you defined a template for a map that uses the same type for key and value, yet the map you are trying to output has two different types for key and value

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your operator only works for maps where the key type and the mapped type are the same (e.g. `std::map<int,int>` or `std::map<char,char>`.

You need two template parameters:

```
template <class K, class V>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ou, const map<K,V>& x) { .... }
```

**Edit**: Note that there is no reason to copy the `map`, so I have modified the operator to take a `const` reference instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your templat arguments are saying that the key and the value in the map are the same. Try changing this:

```
template <class T>
```

to this:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
```

And then updating the rest of your code with these new T1's and T2's.

Answer (score 2):

You have made a template for `class T` but it should instead be for two classes:

```
template <class T, class U>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& ou, map<T,U> x) {
    for(typename map<T,U>::iterator it = x.begin(); it != x.end(); it++) {
        ou << it->first << ": " << it->second << endl;
    }
    return ou;
}
```